# Chrome Manifest v3 creating a cookie for content script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm in a bit of a pickle, hoping someone would have an idea ..

I'm the author of 'New Tab Start Page', and the only remaining issue I have porting
the extension from v2 to v3 is the communication between background and content script.

The functionality concerns changing the user-agent in the content script via javascript
injection using Object.defineProperty, however timing is crucial and therefore anything
that uses chrome.tabs.sendMessage from background is out of the question, as it doesn't
make it in time for the content script to receive, even though it runs at document_start.

For example when done with sendMessage it fails the [aggressive] navigator.userAgent test at webbrowsertools.com/useragent/, as an example.

So I have devised a method in v2 that sets a cookie, which content script can read:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details)
{
    details.responseHeaders.push({name:"Set-Cookie", value:"ESC-AGN75="+encodeURIComponent(agent)+"; Path=/; Max-Age=10"});
    return {responseHeaders:details.responseHeaders};
}, {urls:["<all_urls>"], types:["main_frame"]}, OHROption);
```

And the content script grabs it, etc:

```
var regex = /ESC-AGN75=(.[^;]*)/ig;
var match = regex.exec(document.cookie);
if (match) do_something(decodeURIComponent(match[1]));
document.cookie = "ESC-AGN75=; Path=/; Max-Age=0";
```

Now with v3 there's an issue as it no longer supports webRequest,
so I have changed it to declarativeNetRequest but unfortunately although it works,
it creates strange behavior on certain websites, I suspect issues with csrf tokens:

```
const addrules =
{
    addRules:
    [
        { id:5, priority:5, condition: { resourceTypes:["main_frame"] }, action: { type:"modifyHeaders", responseHeaders: [{ header:"Set-Cookie", operation:"set", value:"ESC-AGN75="+encodeURIComponent(agent)+"; Path=/; Max-Age=10" }] } }
    ]
};
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules(addrules);
```

I am not sure how I can correct this issue, maybe there's something simple I'm missing?

Update: The strange behaviors means that it interferes with website functionality. For example during a login on https://login.sophos.com, there's a POST submit that receives a 400 response instead of 200 when this cookie is enabled. The same issue is not happening when webRequest is used as indicated above, on the same website.

The failed xhr request originates from ajax.ts:157.

Update: After I cleared my cookies I no longer get a 400 however it just reloads the page and asks for email address again & again, very interesting.

Simplifying the cookie in this way: header:"Set-Cookie", operation:"set", value:"XXX" results in no change,- still breaks.

Update: It also affects GMail login functionality, I get too many redirects error message from browser. Just that one cookie! :)

Comment: The approach is correct but "strange behavior" is unclear, please describe it in more detail. Also try adding `; SameSite=Lax` at the end of set-cookie value.

Comment: By strange behaviour I mean that it breaks certain website functionality, I don't know why. For example I cannot use 'https://community.sophos.com/login' to login at all.

Could it possibly have to do with the fact it adds the cookies into more than just the main_frame, hmm..  I have tried adding SameSite=Lax with the same end result.

Comment: It's probably a bug in Chrome. In the future there will be a method to set the config data for the content script, so you'll have to wait until then.

Comment: Could be, but that's not what I wanted to hear :) I thought manifest v3 was around long enough that stuff like this would be fixed. I wish there was a way to set a cookie that only the content script would be able to see.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found a solution to this issue that might help someone (from background):

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab)
{
    var domain = (new URL(tab.url));
    chrome.cookies.set({ "name":"ESC-AGN75", "url":domain.origin, "value":encodeURIComponent(agent) });
});
```

This removes the need for declarativeNetRequest for setting the cookie,
and it also fixes all other issues I've mentioned and the content page
has the required information right away without any delays.

Now the only question remains how to modify user-agent request headers sent by a service worker created by a webpage, but then again this was not possible via webrequest either as best as I can tell ...

The issue is described here:
https://github.com/tarampampam/random-user-agent/issues/203